# Как удалить свойство унаследованное от родительского класса?

Tags: ооп, javascript

Есть родительский класс

```
function costructor_A(){
    this.boom=5;
      .....
    }
```

Наследуем

```
function costructor_G(){
    .....
    }
costructor_G.prototype=new costructor_A
```

Нужно в классе `costructor_G` удалить унаследованное свойство `this.boom`. Я помню, что можно наследовать только свойства, которые имеются в прототипе или только те, которые в самом конструкторе, но хочется именно такой вариант.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// не называйте так классы, используйте camelCase
// и не costructor, а constructor :)
function constructor_A() {
  this.boom=5;
  //.....
}
function constructor_G() {}
constructor_G.prototype = new constructor_A();
constructor_G.prototype.construсtor = constructor_G; // не забываем
delete constructor_G.prototype.boom; // вот она "магия"

new constructor_G().boom // undefined
```

Comment: Спасибо работает